# react-share library has not any function to detect shared link or closed dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-share

I'm using [react-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share) library to share social links. But seem library has not any function to detect user click share button or close button, I have tried `onShareWindowClose` function but it works with both cases shared and closed dialog. I need to detect event to count shared link.